# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/dayjs/dayjs.min.js. ' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I get this issue but i dont use this library.

This is after upgrading vue2 to vue3 with Vitejs.

When I check in source from where it comes the mistake is says its from DaysHighligh.vue which its not from my project.

***package.json***

````
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "dev": "vite",
  "build": "vite build",
  "test": "vite test",
  "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore --fix src"
},
"main": "background.js",
"dependencies": {
  "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
  "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0-0",
  "color-hash": "^1.0.3",
  "gantt-elastic": "^1.0.10",
  "humanize-duration": "^3.21.0",
  "lodash": "^4.17.21",
  "mathjs": "^7.5.1",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
  "throttled-queue": "^1.0.7",
  "vue": "^3.1.0-0",
  "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
  "vue-google-charts": "^0.3.2",
  "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
  "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
  "vue-timeago": "^5.1.2",
  "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
  "vuetify": "^3.1.5",
  "vuetify-upload-button": "^2.0.2",
  "vuex": "^4.0.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
  "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0-0",
  "eslint": "^8.34.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
  "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
  "mkdirp": "^1.0.3",
  "ncp": "^2.0.0",
  "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
  "sass": "^1.23.7",
  "stylus": "^0.54.7",
  "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
  "vite": "^4.1.3",
  "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
  "postcss": "^8.4.21"
},

}```


Is there any of the dependencies which is using this library or I made some mistake ?
````

Comment: I assume it's from one of the dependencies, from the name probably `vue-timeago`. It could be that some of these dependencies were not yet ported to Vue3, you may need to find a replacement or a fork where someone did migrate it

Comment: @Thomas thank you for answer but its not only this dependency because i can see in the package-lock.json there is still the days.js but i can't find which using this library

Comment: There are some tools to show you a dependency graph. It is hard to tell which of these direct dependencies have a transient one to dayjs without it.

Comment: If any one else get this problem madge is the tool which will solve your problem. https://github.com/pahen/madge

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the nodejs version doesn't support the nuxt3 and element plus really well, so the solution is
you need to install pnpm.

```
npm install -g pnpm

//OR

npm install -g @pnpm/exe
```